# how to load image from php server in flutter? I tried but it shows me late initialization error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show my profile picture which is already saved in my database, while I have fetched name, address etc details from my database but it shows error of late initialization,

late Image _photo ;

```
if (!jsondata["error"]) {
      Shared Preferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //  preferences.setString('user_id', jsondata['uid'] );

      controllerName.text = jsondata["user"]["name"];
      controllerAddress.text = jsondata["user"]["address"];
      controllerContact.text = jsondata["user"]["contact_number"];

      setState(() {
        _photo = Image.network(jsondata['image']);

      });

    }
  }

Now using here

child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 55,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          child: _photo != null
                              ? ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  child: _photo,
                                )
                              : (_image != null
                                  ? ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                      child: Image.file(
                                        _image,
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          // color: Colors.grey[200],
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.camera_alt,
                                        // color: Colors.grey[800],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is getting data from the shared preference takes some time. But the widget is being rendered before the _photo variable is being initialised even.
You can resolve the issue by first initialising the _photo variable with a placeholder image like `Image.asset('/path_to_local_image');` and then you can change it when you get the data from shared preferences.

```
var _photo= Image.asset('/path_to_local_image');

if (!jsondata["error"]) {
      Shared Preferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //  preferences.setString('user_id', jsondata['uid'] );

      controllerName.text = jsondata["user"]["name"];
      controllerAddress.text = jsondata["user"]["address"];
      controllerContact.text = jsondata["user"]["contact_number"];

      setState(() {
        _photo = Image.network(jsondata['image']);

      });

    }
  }

return CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 55,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          child: _photo != null
                              ? ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  child: _photo,
                                )
                              : (_image != null
                                  ? ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                      child: Image.file(
                                        _image,
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          // color: Colors.grey[200],
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.camera_alt,
                                        // color: Colors.grey[800],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
.............
.......
```

Comment: its showing the same error